# How can I conditionally hide Next buttons in a formidable multi-page form for multiple field IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formidable

I have found the following script to hide the 'next' button on my formidable multi-step form radio button field ID '18' unless 'Yes' is selected. However, I also want it to hide the next button for some other field IDs too e.g:

Field ID: 64 - Value: second
Field ID: 35 - Value: five

How would I adapt the script below to work for multiple fields/values?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var fieldID = 6;
  var showVal = 'gas';
  var $nextButton = $(".frm_button_submit");

  if (($("input[name^='item_meta[" + fieldID + "]']:checked").val() != showVal) &&     ($("input[type=hidden][name^='item_meta[" + fieldID + "]']").val() != showVal)) {
    $nextButton.css('visibility','hidden');
  }

  $("input[name^='item_meta[" + fieldID + "]']").change(function(){ 
    if ($("input[name^='item_meta[" + fieldID + "]']:checked").val() == showVal){
      $nextButton.css('visibility','visible');
    } else {
      $nextButton.css('visibility','hidden');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Any help is really appreciated as I don't know how to code JavaScript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to store `fieldIds` and `showVals`. Important to note is each index should have a corresponding `fieldId` and `showVal` value,. like

```
var fieldID = [18, 64, 35]; // add more ids here
var showVal = ['yes','text1','text2'];
```

The iterate the whole logic for each `fieldId` like

```
for (i in fieldID) {
 ...
}
```

Updated your code below with the logic

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var fieldID = [18, 64, 35];
  var showVal = ['yes','text1','text2'];
  var $nextButton = $(".frm_button_submit");
  for (i in fieldID) {
    if (($("input[name^='item_meta[" + fieldID[i] + "]']:checked").val() != showVal[i]) && ($("input[type=hidden][name^='item_meta[" + fieldID[i] + "]']").val() != showVal[i])) {
      $nextButton.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }

    $("input[name^='item_meta[" + fieldID[i] + "]']").change(function() {
      if ($("input[name^='item_meta[" + fieldID[i] + "]']:checked").val() == showVal[i]) {
        $nextButton.css('visibility', 'visible');
      } else {
        $nextButton.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that won't work as 'var ShowVal' is not always 'Yes'. Each fieldID has a different 'var' e.g 18=Yes, 64=second, 35=five.

Comment: are these `AND` conditions or `OR` conditons?

Comment: @chappers apply the same principle to `showVal` as used for `fieldIDs` - shouldn't be hard to extrapolate.  Either with a 2nd array (will need an index-based `for` loop instead ) or using an array of objects.

Comment: These are 'or' conditions @tusher

Comment: @chappers : I have updated the code, but as – freedomn-m said, easy to extrapolate with this logix

Comment: Hi @Tushar ive tried that and it doesnt work? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a working sandbox or code snippet of your code?